# Can't get the return of this stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I don't know why this time it doesn't work, I already did this a couple of times but this one is giving me trouble.

This is my C# code :

```
RT_TYPE_STRING query = dba.Database.SqlQuery<RT_TYPE_STRING>("EXEC dbo.CSDN_CreateDemandeAppro @sp1, @sp2, @sp3, @sp4", new SqlParameter("sp1", "20162017"), new SqlParameter("sp2", "590"), new SqlParameter("sp3", "430614451421"), new SqlParameter("sp4", 22.18m)).First();

if (query.NO_DA == "")
{
}
```

And somehow, query is null. I tried executing the stored procedure directly in Management Studio and it returned a `nvarchar` properly.

This is my RT_TYPE_STRING

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RT_TYPE_STRING]
(
    [NO_DA] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_RT_TYPE_STRING] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NO_DA] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And this is my stored procedure, in case you want to look at it:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CSDN_CreateDemandeAppro]
    @EXER_FIN   nvarchar(8),
    @UNIT_ADM   nvarchar(6),
    @NOM_CONT   nvarchar(30),
    @MNT_TOTAL  numeric(15, 2)
AS
    DECLARE
            @NO_DA  nvarchar(8),
            @TYPE   nchar(1),
            @STAT   nchar(1),
            @ETAT   nchar(1),
            @IND_ENG    nchar(1),
            @IND_APPR   nchar(1),
            @TYPE_TRAIT nchar(1),
            @TEL    nvarchar(11),
            @POSTE  nvarchar(5),
            @NOM_ACHET  nvarchar(30),
            @COMMENT_ACHET  nvarchar(255),
            @DATE_CREAT smalldatetime,
            @DATE_MAJ   smalldatetime,
            @DATE_APPR  smalldatetime,
            @CODE_FOND  tinyint,
            @NO_COMM_DOFIN  nvarchar(9),
            @NO_MAG nvarchar(6),
            @NO_SEQ int,
            @NO_DA_OUT int

    BEGIN TRAN
        SELECT @NO_DA = PROC_NO_DA FROM ACH_UNIT_ADM_NUM WHERE UNIT_ADM = @UNIT_ADM and EXER_FIN = @EXER_FIN ;
        UPDATE ACH_UNIT_ADM_NUM SET PROC_NO_DA = @NO_DA + 1 WHERE UNIT_ADM = @UNIT_ADM and EXER_FIN = @EXER_FIN ;
    COMMIT;

    SET @TYPE = '0';
    SET @STAT = '3';
    SET @ETAT = 'C';
    SET @IND_ENG = '0';
    SET @IND_APPR = '0';
    SET @TYPE_TRAIT = '1';
    SET @TEL = NULL;
    SET @POSTE = NULL;
    SET @NOM_ACHET = NULL;
    SET @COMMENT_ACHET = 'APPROVISIONNEMENT.CSDN.QC.CA';
    SET @DATE_CREAT = GETDATE();
    SET @DATE_MAJ = GETDATE();
    SET @DATE_APPR = NULL;
    SET @CODE_FOND = '1';
    SET @NO_COMM_DOFIN = NULL;
    SET @NO_MAG = NULL;
    SET @NO_SEQ = 1;
    SET @NO_DA_OUT = 0;





    INSERT INTO DBO.ACH_DA 
    VALUES (
        @EXER_FIN,
        @NO_DA,
        @UNIT_ADM,
        @TYPE,
        @STAT,
        @ETAT,
        @IND_ENG,
        @IND_APPR,
        @TYPE_TRAIT,
        @NOM_CONT,
        @TEL,
        @POSTE,
        @NOM_ACHET,
        @COMMENT_ACHET,
        @DATE_CREAT,
        @DATE_MAJ,
        @DATE_APPR,
        @MNT_TOTAL,
        @NO_SEQ,
        @CODE_FOND,
        @NO_COMM_DOFIN,
        @NO_MAG);

    Select @NO_DA;
```

SSMS trace :

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.CSDN_CreateDemandeAppro @sp1, @sp2, @sp3, @sp4',N'@sp1 nvarchar(8),@sp2 nvarchar(3),@sp3 nvarchar(12),@sp4 decimal(4,2)',@sp1=N'20162017',@sp2=N'590',@sp3=N'430614451421',@sp4=22.18
```

Comment: add SET NOCOUNT ON?

Comment: I wish it was that simple

Comment: run SQL Profiler and verify the query is actually running the way you think it is? copy/paste the query from Profiler into SSMS and run it exactly as is?

Comment: does EF need you to name the column in the select? "Select @NO_DA AS NO_DA;"?

Comment: @BruceDunwiddie i know the stored procedure is being executed because everything else happen, i mean, there's an insert, and an update, and both of these occur, i verified....

Comment: that's not what I was trying to have you verify by looking in Profiler. I was trying to have you verify the EXACT syntax of the call when EF executes it.

Comment: Is SQL profiler integrated to visual studio or sql management studio ?

Comment: SSMS, under Tools

Comment: Thanks for that, guess we never stop learning

Comment: Adding to my Question

Comment: It seems ok, i'm looking at it and well... nothing strange

Comment: If the insert into DBO.ACH_DA takes place; can you verify that @NO_DA has the correct value there?

Comment: It was my first idea too, but yeah, no_da contains the right # everytime, i even pushed it into a table, thats what i'm currently doing: i could not get the return so i dropped the return in a table and i'm retreiving the value there, but it's the biggest workaround ever... so that's why i made this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hahaha... at the end of my stored procedure replace :

```
Select @NO_DA;
```

by

```
Select @NO_DA NO_DA;
```

So the column actually get a name... NO_DA...

An UNnamed column cannot be returned in entity, for obvious resons... this is phatetic

Comment: (Comment #4, Bruce mentioned this)